# Is variance $\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \DeclareMathOperator{\V}{\mathbb{V}}\V X$ less than $(\E X)^2$?

Tags: time-series, variance, expected-value, moments

I know $Var(X)=E[X^2]−(E[X])^2$.

But is it correct to say $Var(X)$ less than or equal to $E[X^2]$ in the case of dependent variables?

Comment: What do you mean about dependent variables?

Comment: You seem to be asking whether squares of numbers like $E[X]$ must be non-negative.

Comment: Otherwise put, whether $X$ is considered to be dependent (an outcome or response) or not is immaterial, as this is true of any variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb{E}[X]^2$ is non-negative, then the statement:
$$
\text{Var}(X) \leq \mathbb{E}[X^2]
$$
Is true in general. I am not sure what you mean by "dependent variables" here since there is only one random variable $X$.